# How can I hide the doc file from the search engine

Tags: c#, html, jquery, css, asp.net

Im facing a problem, i can found a doc file from search engine from my asp.net website.
Is there any way to hide it?

[search able doc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKHBr.png)

Regards,
Lean

Comment: A robots.txt file may help here - it gets placed in the root directory. However, it doesn't stop malevolent crawlers finding things. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102914/how-to-stop-search-engines-from-crawling-the-whole-website for some discussion on this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you should really do is put documents that you don't want to be publicly visible in a folder so that you can turn "Directory Browsing" off in your hosting environment for that specific folder as well as setting a "Disallow" statement in your robots.txt file.

If you dont disable directory browsing for that folder then people would still be able to navigate to that URL regardless if you have a "Disallow" set in robots.txt.

You can turn directory browsing off for specific folders in your web config like this:

```
<location path="special_directory_name_here">
   <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

You can add a robots .txt file to the root of your website with a "Disallow" statement like this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /docs/
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you don't want to crawl use robot.txt to disallow file.
like

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /owa/
```

Allow allow the path disallow disallow the path. User Agent is search engine trying to crawl.

Just create robot.txt on your root

You can make sure put doc folder under in disallow like

```
   User-agent: *
   Allow: /User-agent: *
   Allow: /
   Disallow: /docs/
```

change docs with the address folder for documents.

Comment: Sorry, im not familiar with robots.txt, how does it works?

Comment: The meta `description` and `keyword` have nothing to do with this. Please remove, it looks like spam...

Comment: yes but I think you can exclude everything a doc easily from Disallow: /docs/ just show where are your doc in robot txt.

Comment: Just add it in the root? no need any additional codes in index.html? jus `User-agent: *
   Allow: /User-agent: *
   Allow: /
   Disallow: /docs/` in robots.txt ?

Comment: It just hiding the docs file from the search engine right? but the user still can access it by entering the download link in the address bar manually right?

Comment: only crawl bot can't read it but anybody can